# What's a good base for hiking in the Italian Alps/Dolomites?

Tags: hiking, alps, dolomites

I want to hike in the Italian Alps or Dolomites at the end of October. I'm looking for a nice village or town where I can stay for a few days. I'm not too adventurous so hikes that are a few hours long would be ideal and since I don't want to drive too much (or at all) I want to be able to reach the trails using public transportation. Also, since it's likely to get cold and/or rainy in the high altitudes I'd prefer if the place isn't too high. Does anyone know a place that could fit this description?

Comment: End of October is kind of late in the season, so you probably want to stay and hike low. My wife used to live in Merano and liked it there.  Depends a bit on what type of hikes you are looking for

Comment: I disagree that the answer will be opinion based.  The OP has specified:  (1) moderate altitude; (2) trails reachable by public transportation; (3) hikes that are a few hours long.  All three are objective cirteria.